# Laravel view working in production but not locally

Tags: php, laravel, apache, xampp, windows-10

When I go to a specific url on my local machine using XAMPP

[image]

In the production server

[image]

Locally the request has no response data available

[image]

---

There are other pages which use the same headers and footer as this one and they load fine both locally and in the production server.

Here's what the edit looks like

```
/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  \App\OrganizationUser  $org_user
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit(Request $request, OrganizationUser $org_user, Organization $model1, User $model2)
{
    // Check if user is admin
    $auth_user = Auth::user();

    $path = $request->path();

    $organization_id = (int)explode('/', $path)[1];

    $user_id = (int)explode('/', $path)[3];

    //dd($org_user->load('user')->load('organization'));

    if($auth_user->isAdmin()) {

        return view('organizations.users.edit', [
                                                'org_user' => $org_user->load('user')->load('organization')->where('id', $user_id)->first(),
                                                'organizations' => $model1::where('id', $organization_id)->get(['id', 'name']),
                                                'users' => $model2->get(['id', 'name'])
                                                ]);        
    
    } else {


        abort(404);

    }
    
}
```

---

What have I tried so far

1. Clear configuration cache

```
php artisan config:clear
```

2. Clearing route cache

```
php artisan route:clear
```

3. Clearing view cache

```
php artisan view:clear
```

4. Clearing event cache

```
php artisan event:clear
```

5. Clearing application cache

```
php artisan cache:clear
```

6. Clearing all cache

```
php artisan optimize:clear
```

7. Clearing content from Composer's cache

```
composer dump-autoload
```

8. Clearing NPM cache

```
npm cache clean --force
```

9. Use a different browser (tested both in Chrome and Firefox).
10. Restart Apache through the XAMPP console.
11. Restart the computer.

---

### Edit

Upon request, here's the .htaccess present in the /public folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Enable debugging in `.env` if you haven't already. Take a look at the bottom of your project's `laravel.log`, there might be some error details there.

Comment: it seems you local server is not able to serve file

Comment: Replace `AllowOverride none` to `AllowOverride All`  everyWhere and restart apache

Comment: @mohammadasghari just tested that and changing both in httpd.conf and httpd-xampp.conf the `AllowOverride none` to `AllowOverride All`. Also, the `Require all denied` to `Require all granted`.

Comment: @brombeer it's set to true and no errors in the `php_error_log`.

Comment: Add `httaccess` to your question.

Comment: Nothing in your `storage/logs/laravel.log` either?

Comment: @brombeer also not

Comment: @mohammadasghari just included

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I've managed to make it work was to disable XAMPP's Apache and run instead

```
php artisan serve
```

Now I'm able to use it just fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this, change your httacces file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Anyway, you solved your problem and that's enough ;)

Comment: Kind of... it's actually a workaround given that before Apache was runnning always in the background and i wouldn't need to keep doing the `php artisan serve`... now it feels more like programming in Angular with the `ng serve` :P